# Arrange the GridView items from the top

Tags: android, gridview

I downloaded a source and into that source

Used one GridView

I want the items to be top-down

But the order is from bottom to top

what should I do

To be arranged from top to bottom

Like the photo below

[image]

These are my codes

```
<GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:numColumns="6"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:id="@+id/grid_view_item_details_1"/>
```

And

```
public class SquaresAdapters extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mActivity;
private List<Square> mList;

public SquaresAdapters(Activity activity, List<Square> squares) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mList = squares;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View choice;
    LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        choice = inflater.inflate(R.layout.square_view, parent, false);
        TextView textChoice = (TextView) choice;
        if (!mList.get(position).getState()) {
            textChoice.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.background_squares_with_empty_state));
        } else {
            textChoice.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.background_squares_with_populated_state));
        }
        textChoice.setText(mList.get(position).getLetter());
        if (mList.get(position).getTextColor().equals("black")) {
            textChoice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.black_dark));
        } else {
            textChoice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.green16));
        }
    } else {
        choice = convertView;
    }
    return choice;
}
public void setSquaresList(List<Square> list) {
    mList = list;
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just rearrange the content of your mList?

Comment: Yunus Kulyyev  You explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ready source and you have this problem
May be somewhere from the code this will make the items appear in reverse

Search and find that code and edit or delete it

Codes like

`Collections.reverse(mList);`

And

`for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--)`

Etc

Answer (score 0):

reverse the data whcih are passed to the adapter like

```
public SquaresAdapters(Activity activity, List<Square> squares) {
  mActivity = activity;
  mList = squares;
  Collections.reverse(mList);// this will reverse the list
}
```

reverse here also if you set the data after adapter creation

```
public void setSquaresList(List<Square> list) {
   mList = list;
   Collections.reverse(mList);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

change getItem to this

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}
```

Comment: But if you reverse that, he will get 123, 456 instead of 321,654

Comment: he is using `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` I think this will work normally

Comment: aww did not see that. Yeah, then this should work fine

Comment: @lkhgfj what is the output you get ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid solution honestly but it will give you an idea:

```
public SquaresAdapters(Activity activity, List<Square> squares) {
  mActivity = activity;
  mList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
     mList.add(squares.get(i));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     mList.add(squares.get(i));
  }
}
```